# MariaDB can we create a functional index ( index based on a function )

Tags: mariadb, database-indexes

can i create a functional index in MariaDB like in Oracle we can:

```
create index fnc_idx on table_name (to_char(date_col, 'MM-YYYY'));
```

or any alternate solution...?
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculated columns as approach:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  -- add calculated column
  `order_month` VARCHAR(6) AS (CONCAT(MONTH(order_date), YEAR(order_date))) PERSISTENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- add calculated column index
  INDEX (`order_month`)
);
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=695b8d92fc11bb2325cf07ee4b076576&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Comment: thanks @Slava Rozhnev for help, will check it. regards :)